Using heat pumps for harnessing animal heat
Why aren't heat pumps used to harness animal heat (such as in cows or pigs), later to be released at a central location at around the boiling point of water to generate electricity?

Would you generate enough electricity to run the heat pump?

@DaveTweed At scale, I would assume breakeven or a little more would be possible. Some commercial heat pumps (in Norway) do raise the temperature to ~boiling temperature, so I think the engineering is mostly done.

So if you can only do "a little more than breakeven", what's the economic motive for doing it at all?

@DaveTweed It is usable energy, and it can cool the livestock.

This question needs more detail. How do you propose to arrange heat pumps to collect heat from animals? Would the animals wear them? Would the animals be confined to a closed chamber were their body heat warms up chamber & the heat is harvested that way?

This is one of those things where I suggest you try it and find out. I suspect that the harvester's heat flow restriction will heat the critter more than its harvested energy can cool it- that the critter (and world in general) would be cooler without the gear. In order to flow heat from critters to a central location at the boiling point of water, critter must be hotter (heat flows hot to cold). Crispy steamed critter?

Why not investigate the possibility of harnessing all the hot air from politicians and some of those conferences?

Do a web search on "Maxwell's Demon".  That should give you a starting point.

The electricity generated this way would not be sufficient to run the heat pump in the first place.
